# Compute the required size for a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to setup a messaging UI similar to the one used in iOS7, using a UICollectionView (to take advantage of UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclassing with UIDynamics). Given a NSString, I need to compute the necessary size for the UITextView so that the text isn't cut. I have tried `sizeWithAttributes:` and Core Text's `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints` method, but both of these give smaller heights than they should. I have also tried using a hidden text view to compute the frame, but it's relatively expensive to fill a textView for each message. I've setup a test project [here](https://github.com/axelcdv/messageTests).
Any idea what I might be missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try converting your NSString to an NSAttrbutedString and using:

[`- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:options:context:;`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/boundingRectWithSize%3aoptions%3acontext%3a)

You will also want to eliminate the edge insets from your UITextView using these three:

```
textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
[textView setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
[textView.textContainer setLineFragmentPadding:0];
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great, and actually `[textView setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];`is enough to fix the size issue I was having.

Comment: Yeah, I overkill it because it's such a new API.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit older than iOS7, which i'm guessing you could just use autolayout constraints (that's how I would do it). But this is how it's been done by a lot of apps, and will point you in the right direction :

[Dynamic Heights for textviews](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/)

Comment: Thanks! Well I'm using autolayout, which mostly works pretty well, but in that case I can't really avoid using a fixed width constraint, which I have to calculate depending on the text size... But I'll have a look at your link, see if it works